# Unable to get wcf to show https in wsdl

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, https, wsdl

I have created a test WCF webservice that is to run over https only. It works but is showing http in the wsdl - is this correct? 
Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <services>
      <service name="MyNamespace.WebServicesClass">
        <endpoint address ="" binding ="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract ="ITestWebService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
       <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and this is what I see in IE

```
wsdl:service name="WebServicesClass">
wsdl:port name="**BasicHttpBinding**_ITestWebService" binding="tns:**BasicHttpBinding**_ITestWebService"
soap:address location="**http**://xxxxxxx.com/TestWebService.svc"/
/wsdl:port
/wsdl:service
```

Why is http and why is BasicHttpBinding when I don't have that in my web.config?

Comment: Do you mean in wsdl it shows http://localhost. can you attach the wdsl?

Comment: In the above snippet from my wsdl, you can see the soap:address is http - should it not be https? And what is the port name BasicHttpBinding, should it now be wsHttpBinding?